# How to add two multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to do the following:

```
array1 = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 10], [4, 30]]
array2 = [[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 5], [4, 10]]
```

I want to add two arrays in such a way that the second element of each subarray will be added. I want the following output.

```
result = [[1,20],[2,30],[3,15],[4,40]]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
[array1, array2].transpose.map{|(k, v1), (_, v2)| [k, v1 + v2]}
# => [[1, 20], [2, 30], [3, 15], [4, 40]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach as below :

```
array1 = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,30]]
array2 = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,5],[4,10]]

Hash[array1].merge(Hash[array2]) { |key,old,new| old + new }.to_a
# => [[1, 20], [2, 30], [3, 15], [4, 40]]
```

Taking the help of [`merge(other_hash){|key, oldval, newval| block}`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) .

Comment: The OP's code has smell. It should have been arrays in the first place.

Comment: I am saying that the OP should have made them as hashes. It does not look right that the OP made them as arrays. Then, you would not needed to convert to and from hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a combination of [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
result = array1.zip(array2).map { |l, r| [l[0], l[1] + r[1]] }
#=> [[1, 20], [2, 30], [3, 15], [4, 40]]
```

However, key-value pairs are often best treated as a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html). Among other operations, this will allow you to [`#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
hash1
#=> {1=>10, 2=>20, 3=>10, 4=>30}
hash2
#=> {1=>10, 2=>10, 3=>5, 4=>10}
result = hash1.merge(hash2) { |_, l, r| l + r }
#=> {1=>20, 2=>30, 3=>15, 4=>40}
```

Comment: How can you do this with a multidimensional array with strings?

Comment: Same way. Give it a try!