# Find largest sub array out of ruby multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to find out the largest sub array out of a multidimensional array in ruby.
I have a multidimensional array as follows :

```
array = [[1,20],[2,40],[5,100],[7,15],[9,22]]
```

I want the first element of the sub array which second element is largest like in the above example I want the `5` as an output because second element of sub array `[5,100]` is largest which is `100`. The output would be `5`.

And if more then one element are maximum than i want all these.

Ex: 
array = [[1,20],[2,40],[5,100],[7,15],[9,22],[12,100]]

The out put in this case would be [5,12]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) method to select the max element, and then project that element to the result value.

```
array.max_by{|a| a[1]}[0]
```

UPDATE:

If you want all the elements with the maximum value, you can first get the max value from the array, and then filter the array with that value.

```
max_value = array.max_by{|a| a[1]}[1]
results = array.select{|a| a[1] == max_value}.map(&:first)
```

You may use one line expression, but I think that's less readable

```
array.group_by{|a| a[1]}.max_by{|k,v| k}[1].map(&:first)
```

Comment: +1 for linking the documentation. I would probably go with a hybrid of this and @dimuch's answer (since the question references the *second* element, rather than *`last`*): `array.max_by { |a| a[1] }.first #=> 5`

Comment: Thanks Arie ..one more case i forget to mention is i want first element of all the sub element which are maximum,ex. [[1,20],[2,40],[5,100],[7,15],[9,22],[12,100]] in this case output would be [5,12]

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
array.max_by(&:last).first
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Following updated question.

You *could* use [Arie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317167/78845) to compute `largest`:

```
largest = array.max_by { |a| a[1] }[1] #=> 100
```

Then combine [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) with [`Array#compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) to get:

```
array.map { |a| a.first if a[1] == largest}.compact #=> [5, 12]
```

#### Better still...

Use a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge), as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22323009/78845) to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22248842/78845)...

```
hash
#=> {1=>20, 2=>40, 5=>100, 7=>15, 9=>22, 12=>100}
```

Largest value:

```
hash.values.max
#=> 100
```

Key-value pairs with the largest value:

```
hash.select { |k, v| v == hash.values.max }
#=> {5=>100, 12=>100}
```

Keys with the largest value:

```
hash.select { |k, v| v == hash.values.max }.keys
#=> [5, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a =  [[1,20],[2,40],[5,100],[7,15],[9,22],[12,100]]

max = a.map(&:last).max

a.select{|x|x.last==max}.map(&:first) #=> [5, 12]
```